# selecionar campos SQL apartir de determinada fecha

Tags: php, sql-server

Tengo una tabla que tiene registros diarios (tabla de pruebas) desde hace 2 años

quiero obtener el resultado apartir de determinada generada por php fecha "$last_periodo_date"

```
$last_periodo_date = date("Y-m", strtotime("- 1 month"))."-25" ;
```

$last_periodo_date me regresa siempre el dia 25 del mes pasado en formato año-mes-dia (ejemplo 2018-06-25)
Nota: $Id_usuario es un campo que comparo en tro lado parareferir a usuarios espesificos

```
$sql_asistencia = "SELECT * FROM asistencia where id_usuario=$Id_usuario AND asistencia ='1' AND fecha > $last_periodo_date  ";
```

aqui funciona todo bien asta 'AND fecha > $last_periodo_date'

```
$params = array();
$options =  array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql_asistencia2 , $params, $options );
```

esta parte tiene que ver con mi server SQL

```
$resultado = sqlsrv_num_rows( $stmt );
```

Este es mi result pero no me esta entregando resultado , si retiro de  el seect me muestra todos los resultados correctamente , pero al mostrar la fecha no

Answer (score 1):

Deverias convertir la variable fecha php en fecha sql.-

```
$sql_asistencia = "SELECT * FROM asistencia where id_usuario=$Id_usuario AND asistencia ='1' AND fecha > convert(datetime, $last_periodo_date, 111) ";
```

111 Es el formato yyyy/mm/dd